# Uninitialized value issue in tf.mean_per_class_accuracy for RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I run a tensorflow session for tf.metrics.mean_per_class_accuracy operation for RNN, my code returns FailedPreconditionError like:

> ```
> FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value mean_accuracy/count
>    [[Node: mean_accuracy/count/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, 
>       _class=["loc:@mean_accuracy/count"], 
>       _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](mean_accuracy/count)]]
> ```

I wonder if I initialized the tensors before operate the mean per class accuracy then the weight and biases tensors are initialized so that these are differ from trained tensor values.

My code is same as below:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np

    x_raw = np.random.rand(10,3,3)
    y_raw = np.random.randint(0,high=2,size=10)
    x_test = np.random.rand(1,3,3)
    y_test = np.random.randint(0,high=2,size=1)

    tf.reset_default_graph()
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3, 3])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])

    def rnn(x):
        l = {'w': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 2])),
             'b': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2]))}
        x = tf.transpose(x, (1,0,2))
        x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, 3))
        x = tf.split(x, 3, axis=0)
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(5)
        out, stt = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
        o = tf.matmul(out[-1], l['w'])+l['b']
        return o

    pr = rnn(x)
    co = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y, logits=pr)
    om = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(co)
    cr = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pr,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
    ac0 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(cr,tf.float32))
    ac1 = tf.metrics.mean_per_class_accuracy(y,pr,2)

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    c, _ = sess.run([co,om], feed_dict={x:x_raw[:5], y:tf.Session().run(tf.one_hot(y_raw[:5],2))})
    print(sess.run(ac0, feed_dict={x:x_test, y:tf.Session().run(tf.one_hot(y_test,2))}))
    print(sess.run(ac1, feed_dict={x:x_test, y:tf.Session().run(tf.one_hot(y_test,2))}))
```

The error massage is raised when my console approach the line for operate 'ac1' tensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.metrics.mean_per_class_accuracy` creates variables in the `tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES`, rather than `GLOBAL_VARIABLES`. This means they aren't being initialized by your `tf.global_variables_initializer()`.

Fortunately, there's a corresponding `tf.local_variables_initializer()` to help you out. Throw it in alongside your global initializer and you should be good to go!

```
sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, does 'local initializer' not initailize the variables which have been trained by tensorflow trainer? Does the 'local initializer' reset only graph variables such as gradients except all of weights and biases?

Comment: `local_variables_initializer` initializes all variables added to the `tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES` collection. Typically, variables that do not affect the training of the graph should be put here (like moving averages for evaluation). Gradients and the like will normally be computed (i.e. not `tf.Variable`s), though there are some `tf.Variable`s that are associated with optimizers which would be `GLOBAL`.